# Turn on an LED when a device connects to Raspberry Pi through WiFi

Tags: gpio, wifi, hotspot

I am doing a project for which I need to make an LED ON when a device connects with Raspberry Pi. Raspberry Pi will act as access point and will provide network to other devices. I found a example on [Raspberry Pi forum](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=96453&p=670617) but this is different. I tried it also (after making some changes) when Raspberry Pi connects with the access point but it didn't work. 
Please help!

**EDIT:** It worked now, I was doing wrong first.
Now how can I change it to make it work when Raspberry Pi act as access point and turn ON an LED when a device connects with it? I followed this [guide](https://learn.adafruit.com/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-wifi-access-point?view=all) to make raspberry pi access point.

I have connected an LED with GPIO17. I wrote a simple Python script and name it *wifiLED.py*:

```
#!/bin/env python

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(17, True)
```

I put this script into following bash script *wifi_LED.sh*. I found my gateway address by `$route -n`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# ping the gateway address
/bin/ping -q -c 192.168.0.1 > /dev/null

if [ $? -eq  0 ]
then
  echo "Network active"
  sudo python /home/pi/wifiLED.py  

else
  echo "Network down"
fi
```

When I do `sh wifi_LED.sh`, it turn ON LED connected with GPIO17.

Comment: Code?  Wiring? Photos?

Comment: I edited my question sir.

Answer (score 2):

I know it won't answer your question but I'll give you a hint as I don't know `hostapd`. Enable logging in `hostapd.conf` and use the generated log to capture connect events from a script. You might want to run a consumer script like this, for instance:

```
my-log-analyzer.sh < /var/log/hostapd.log
```

Assuming `hostapd.conf` allows you to specify a custom log file path.

A typical pseudo code would look like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
while read LINE; do
    # Detect connect events in $LINE, which is read from the log
    ...
    # If connect event detected then run script to light the LED
done
```

As the log file might be really verbose an enhanced version would filter connect events prior to run the log analyser:

```
grep 'connect' /var/log/hostapd.log | my-log-analyzer.sh
```

If `hostapd` allows connect hooks then it's trivial as you'd run a script every time a client connects to the access point.

Comment: Thank you. I also have problem with this guide setup. When I use RPi as AP, I can't connect with the internet anymore. Can you suggest me any other method or guide through which I can solve both problems?

Comment: From where can you not connect to the internet anymore? The Pi or other wireless clients (that are connected to the Pi)? Otherwise [here's another guide](https://frillip.com/using-your-raspberry-pi-3-as-a-wifi-access-point-with-hostapd/), much simpler, which takes advantage of `dnsmasq` a full-fledged DHCP and DNS forwarder.

Comment: Yes the RPi can't connect with my existing network. I also want to use Internet on RPi while it is also providing network to clients.

Comment: «*Yes the RPi can't connect with my existing network*» — well I'm not sure I follow you now. Can you ping the Pi from a client wirelessly connected to your Raspberry Pi's SSID (aka the wireless network ID that you defined in `hostapd.conf`)?